# How do Google contacts change without me making the changes?

Tags: iphone, imac, ms-office, contacts, google

I have windows and apple devices but mostly apple.  iMac, iPhone and iPad plus a Dell XPS.

Contacts are from google.  I've noticed for quite a while that a certain category of contacts are changed without my consent.

I have not been able to find any settings related to this so far.

The category of contacts I will say are businesses or notational.  I'm in the habit of storing businesses with the business name in the Last name field.  Yes I know there is a company field but why clutter an export with an extra field to review.  The fields are not functional so how I choose to document them shouldn't matter.

Here are examples:
[image: before and after]

It makes my contact list messy to read but more importantly, I haven't requested the system to make these changes that I'm aware of and haven't explicitly given permission to change my data, so why is it being changed?

When this first happened, I thought somehow it was a one-off thing but I've corrected many of them and I'm getting tired of it. How do I make it stop?

I've seen similar stuff posted about contacts on android so I also checked my phone settings as well but so far, I haven't found anything that stops this from happening.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you using iCloud

Comment: No. Just gmail and local apps